# Loading controllers when navigating through screens

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I'm currently using `directives` in my `ionic` app, there directives are normally bind to a `angular controller`. So my problem is, when I navigate through the app, my controllers are not loading (loads for the first time) and hence I cannot setup some initial values.

Following is an example

1. I navigate to `users` screen/page
2. `users controller` loads (When I check with Chrome dev tools)
3. I navigate to home screen
4. I navigate back to `users` screen

At this point I expect `users controller` to load again, to setup my initial values, but it's not happening

I'm not sure if this is the default behavior, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using nested states, parent.child1, parent.child2, parent only loads 1 for the entire hierarchy, changing from child1 to child 2 will not reload the parent controller, thats one of the pros of using ui-router.

also note that with ionic latest version they introduced view caching so, the controller is only instanciated once for each view, to prevent that you need to use

```
cache-view="false"
```

in your ion-view

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/